# Ajax POST method converts my "+" value in a string to " " why?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I cant figure out why in ajax post "+" sign converts to " ".please explain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `encodeURIComponent()` function to turn your data in valid encoded data for the request:

```
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.send(encodeURIComponent(postdata));
```

Comment: This will break data. You need to encode **each component** separately. Encoding the whole `postdata` in one go will convert all the `=` and `&` which have special meaning

Answer (score 4):

It's how URL encoding works.  If you want a plus sign it's %2B, but you should really just escape or encode the data you're sending to the server.  Type "a+b c" in [here](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/urlencode.php).

Answer (score 3):

"+" is the url encoded symbol for space. As such, when your post data is decoded the "+" is converted to a space.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that you are using the `+` sign in an URL, where it is rightly converted into a space, as `+` is the URLEncoded representation of a space character.

Run `escape()` on whatever value you are putting into your URL to get it into URL-encoded form.

Answer (score 2):

This is because [URL Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) converts spaces to `+` since spaces aren't valid in URLs.

Normally characters are converted to `%` followed by two hex digits, but having `+` instead of `%20` makes URLs more readable.

If you encode your `+` as `%2B` that should work.

Answer (score 1):

That's just standard url encoding.  Plus signs are converted to spaces on the server.  If you want to pass a plus sign you need to escape it as %2b.